# Fit map to show world always

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Right now what I'm trying to do is zoom the map in and out based on screen size, so that you can always see basically every piece of land in the world. I'm not worried about the repeating world, but I ideally want to keep it centered basically on the west coast of Africa, like a typical map.

I have something that looks as follows:

```
function fitMap() {
    if ($) {
        var height = $(window).height();
        var width = $(window).width();
        //Put map into full screen
        $('#map').css({position: "absolute", top: "0", left: "0", right: "0", bottom:"0"});

        if ((height < 586 && width < 1095) || height < 325 || (width < 700 && height > 586)) {
            map.setZoom(1);
        }
        else if (width >= 1500 && height > 900) {
            map.setZoom(3);
        } 
        else {
            map.setZoom(2);
        }
    }
};

//Fit the map more appropriately to screen sizes.
window.onload = fitMap;
window.onresize = fitMap;
```

I find this to be really hacky and it works if I were to try and put this on a 1920x1080 all the way down to a small 1024x768 but I didn't see anything in Leaflet that would allow me to do this. One idea I had was to create an invisible feature group that basically creates a perimeter from dateline to dateline and use `.getBounds()` like this: [Centering Leaflet map with getbounds and related issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445125/centering-leaflet-map-with-getbounds-and-related-issues)

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Is this Google Map v3? if yes update the tags, and what you are trying to achieve is not clear, please explain.

Comment: It is not. Just Leaflet with OpenStreet maps

Answer (score 7):

Leaflet offers a [`fitWorld()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitworld) to do just this.

You would use this by calling `map.fitWorld();`, and here's a [full example](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/qQL67/).

Comment: I don't think that that solution is working the way I am describing, however the description seems correct. 

Here is a demo I created that shows what I made: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9187486/IP%20Maps/index.html

If you resize your browser window to be small or extra large, it will re-zoom the map more appropriately than `fitWorld()`. My solution more accurately keeps the continents within the width of the browser. `fitWorld()` seems more liberal about zooming out a lot.

Comment: Ah, so you want it to re-zoom when the user resizes the map?

Comment: I guess not necessarily resizes but I left that in there for good measure. It was more so the map acts "responsive" CSS3 style, so on any screen that I put it on, it'll look the same. If I were to leave it at level 2 zoom for all screens then it would look way too zoomed out on the big screens, hence zooming in.

Comment: You could also use the combo of `fitWorld` and the `resize` event to re-fit the map on resize - `map.on('resize', function(e) {map.fitWorld();});`. I updated my jsFiddle to do this.

Comment: I made one more change that should might the effect you're going for - http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/qQL67/

Comment: Old thread, but for future finders, you can use `map.fitWorld().zoomIn();`

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that `fitWorld` takes `zoomSnap` into account, so if you are using the default value of `1` and call `fitZoom` on resize, the map doesn't really fit well in a lot of situations. Decrease `zoomSnap` to a value that's okay for you. 
I also recommend setting `animate` to false with this approach:

```
map.on( 'resize', () => {
    map.fitWorld( { animate: false } );
} );
```